# SQLAlchemy session error while creating object with m2m relation

Tags: python, flask, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm new to SQLAlchemy and Flask. I'm trying to create an object (**book**) with m2m relation and append an existed object (**tag_2**) to the relation:

```py
book = Book(title='title')

tag_1 = Tag(name='tag')
book.tags.append(tag_1)     # New tag works well

tag_2 = Tag.query.get(123)  # Get existed tag by id
print(tag_2)                # >>> Tag #123
book.tags.append(tag_2)     # ERROR: Object '<Tag at ...>' is already attached to session '1'

self.session.add(book)
self.session.commit()
```

Have no problems creating new related objects, but can't point the existing object.

My models:

```py
book_tags = db.Table('book_tags', db.metadata,
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id')),
    db.Column('book_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('book.id'))
)


class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)


class Book(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=book_tags)
```

I use sqlite as DB.

Comment: Do you do all this in single database session? This error usually occurs when you select `Tag` using one session and then you try to store it using different session. Poor man's way to debug this is to print out session.

Comment: I use flask_resty as a REST framework. I believe it creates only one session in this case. I'll try to create new one for selecting `Tag`.

Comment: You need just one, same. From your comment on answer bellow you already have 2 sessions. Make sure you create only one session per request. Would help if you posted how your controller looks.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you use different `self.session` for getting `Tag` and for getting `Book` you are then trying to append `Tag` to. In order to be able to append object **A** to object **B** they must both exist in same session.

It's hard to tell how you create your session because your post only shows code that operates with it but make sure you have only one session.

Answer (score 0):

```py
tags = db.relationship(
    'Tag',
    secondary=book_tags,
    backref=db.backref('book', lazy='dynamic')
)
```

You need to add backref in m2m relationship because 
*Using backref just automates the creation of a relationship property at the other end. backref='book' is somewhat akin to having book = db.relationship('book') explicitly in the Tag class (+ back population). Using the backref() object you can pass arguments to that relationship.*

Comment: Same error but with `Book` instead of `Tag`:

```sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '<Book at 0x1057c9510>' is already attached to session '1' (this is '2')```

Comment: This is root cause of problem `is already attached to session '1' (this is '2')`, you need to do both operations in single session.